# Can a person residing in Singapore on a 5-month Employment Pass apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, residency

I'm an Indian student currently in Singapore as a Research Associate with a TEP valid for five months and have just been selected for an internship in Switzerland this summer.

Is it possible for me to obtain a Schengen visa from the Swiss Embassy in Singapore?

Comment: @pnuts the swiss internship is 2.5 months while the Singapore one is 5 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question since I just wrapped up both internships. I was able to apply for, and get, the Swiss visa from the Swiss Embassy in Singapore since I was a Singaporean resident at that time (since I had the TEP).

There were no hassles getting it but I would recommend apply early and like @JonathanReez mentioned, it's a good idea to email the embassy in question before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

The Swiss embassy in Singapore requires the [following documents](https://www.eda.admin.ch/content/dam/countries/countries-content/singapore/en/H%20Tourism.pdf) to prove residency:

> Proof of legal residence in Singapore, **valid for at least 3 months
>   beyond the intended date of departure from the Schengen territory**.
>   Original plus 1 photocopy back and front of **Employment Pass /
>   Permanent Resident card and re-entry permit / Dependent Pass / Student
>   Pass**.

So the answer is **yes**, as long as your Employment Pass is valid for 3 months beyond your intended date of return to Singapore.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. There is one problem though, the Swiss internship is after the Singapore one. I won't be coming back to Singapore post that.

Comment: @Idris then you should apply for the Schengen visa from India, I'm afraid

Comment: So I'll have to come back to India from Singapore in the middle of my internship and go to the embassy there? Is there any other way that the Swiss embassy at Singapore could grant the Schengen visa if I have the round trip tickets (from and to India)?

Comment: @Idris I'd try emailing the embassy to see if they can make an exception